# Using Oracle UCM JSON data in fullcalendar?

Tags: json, fullcalendar, oracle-ucm

Is there a way to fetch data from Oracle UCM's JSON option and use this in Full Calendar.  I createed a service to return data from calendar data in UCM, and want to display the events using fullcalendar.

Here is an example feed that I get back:

```
"ResultSets": {
{
"SQLLMCal": {
"fields": [
{ "name": "SINGLE_ELEMENT" },
{ "name": "Start" },
{ "name": "SCHOOL_TYPE" },
{ "name": "SCHOOL_TYPE_ID" },
{ "name": "Title" },
{ "name": "ENTRY_SIDE_GROUP" }
],
"rows": [
[
"141",
"3/17/11 12:00 AM",
"Elementary",
"3",
"Big Burger",
"1"
]
]
}
}
}
```

Thanks, Ken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to parse your own data using a custom events function:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/

Comment: This has been the direction I have been working on.  I get caught up in the systax with callbacks.  I appreciate the direction!

Comment: According to the documentation, the return from events_function is an array of event objects.  I have a row object that I can loop through, but am not sure how to create the appropriate event object. I tried to use `var event = new Event();`, but that did not work.  How can I construct a new event object that I can populate with title and start values?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
 var now = new Date();
 $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  firstDay: now.getDay(),
  events: function(callback) {
   var events = [];
   events.push({"title":"This is test 2","start":now});
   alert("Date: "+events[0].start);
   callback(events);
  }
 });
});
` - I thought this would work, but doesn't display any events on the calendar.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, great example of "problem exists between keyboard and chair"!  I just had to stare at the documentation and the answer was right there.

In my code, I have the following:
events: function(callback) {

By definition, this MUST be
events: function(start, end, callback) {

Once I added the start and end parameters, everything worked perfectly.

Thank you Adam for pointing me the the right direction!

Ken